# How to edit default pdfx metadata?

Tags: pdf, texniccenter, pdfx

I keep trying to compile my document using pdfx; however, the default title does not seem to change. I am trying to input new metadata as follows:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{PhDThesis.xmpdata}
\Title{New Title}
\Author{A. Baker\sep C. Kneader}
\Keywords{cookies\sep muffins\sep cakes}
\Publisher{Baking International}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[letterpaper, twoside, 12pt]{report}
\usepackage[a-3b]{pdfx}
```

However, the default PDF title "Baking through the ages" ([see PDF/X documentation](ftp://ftp.fu-berlin.de/tex/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/pdfx/pdfx.pdf)) always remains.

Am I missing something basic here?

I am using TeXnicCenter and Foxit PDF reader.

Comment: Have you deleted `PhDThesis.xmpdata` after changing? The filecontents environment does not override files.

Comment: Wow, yep, that worked! Thanks. Feel free to make this a formal answer, which I will accept.

Comment: @TeXnician Although it is slightly OT: The `novel` package has built-in PDF/X, which does not load package `pdfx` or related others. In `novel` the XMP data is dynamically generated directly from the file metadata, without an external xmpdata file. Now, `novel` is unsuited to digital file distribution (it is for paper-print only) so it does not allow a variety of metadata that digital publications would have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a `filecontents` environment. This environment does not replace an existing file, so after one LaTeX run you will have your metadata file. If you alter the content of the environment you need to delete the produced file and rerun LaTeX on the TeX file, which in turn generates the new version.

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly. Do you know if there is a way to have it overwrite the xmpdata file when rerunning LaTeX?

Comment: @Shinobii Unfortunately, I do not know any way to do so.